# Exibir dados dados de um ID na tabela em um textBox - C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou precisando fazer um `select` no banco de dados para capturar o `id` do ultimo produto cadastro, vou fazer um incremento e mostra-lo em um `textbox` em meu formulário de cadastro. O meu intuito é mostrar para o usuário qual será o próximo `id` de produto que será cadastrado.

Como posso transformar essa informação vinda do `select` para exibi-la no `textBox`?

Comment: Qual o banco de dados? E se duas pessoas forem efetuar o cadastro ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: o @RobertodeCampos está completamente certo, recomendo usar uma `sequence` no banco para resolver esse problema

Comment: já pensou que o id, na maioria dos casos, pouco importa pro usuário ?! exibir uma previsão de qual id será gerado no banco de dados então... não vejo benefício algum em fazer isso, só trará problemas e dificuldades

Comment: então na verdade era esse um componente de uma gambiarra, preciso na verdade do dado do id para que quando o produto for cadastrado eu mandar esta informação para outra tabela do banco de dados SQL Server

Comment: @JoãoÁvila não é a melhor pratica, mas você pode fazer um `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) +1 FROM TABELA` e você terá o próximo ID a ser inserido.